# Warning: PDO::__construct() — помогите!

Tags: modx, revo

Сайт (MODx Revo), который нормально открывался два дня назад, сегодня выдаёт ошибку:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/users/l/llallals/domains/site.ru/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php on line 3056
```

Никаких работ произведено не было, ошибка возникла как-то сама по себе. Она приводит к неисправной работе компонентов gallery, getResources. А также, невозможно зайти в админку — пишет "Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль", хотя они правильные, и восстановить пароль по почте нельзя, пишет "Пользователь с таким адресом электронной почты или именем не найден". При этом логин/пароль и почта рабочие и правильные, я по ним заходил перед этим.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?**
Пароль не удаётся восстановить через БД MySQL, т.е. смена пароля почему-то не помогает (зайти в админку по-прежнему нельзя).

Я подозреваю, что данная проблема возникла после перехода хостинга на новую версию PHP 7.0 (хотя не знаю, может ли быть такая взаимосвязь). Потому что вчера мне на почту пришло от них письмо о PHP 7.0 и со вчерашнего дня сайт перестал работать.

Догадываюсь также, что данную проблему можно решить обновлением компонентов gallery, getResources и, возможно, всей MODx. Но мне как-то нужно зайти в админку.

Это всё догадки. Если кто-то точно знает, в чём проблема — пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: а база точно работает?

Comment: Работает, но надо проверить. Спасибо!